# KubeClient was disconnected from the master

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have migrated to eks1.23 from eks1.21 and i have been seeing this error, on most of the services, it looks frequent, what does this error mean and how can we fix this error?

```
   xxx KubeClient was disconnected from the master, attempting to reconnect
    xxx watcher attempting to reconnect to Kubernetes API in 100 MS
```

Comment: I would not call it an error. It is a logs statement that the connetion was lost, and that it will try to re-connect.

Comment: right, but we have been seeing this a lot,